# Toggle Div Style Between Opened (Display: Block) and Closed (Display: None) With jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have two divs that appear like this:

[image]

The idea is that when you close the bottom div (click on the 'X'), it should disappear.

And when you close the top div, it should disappear, and also the bottom div should slide up and take its place.

I'm very new to jQuery, but this is my first attempt:

```js
function initAnnouncements() {
  $(document)
    // Closes announcement modules
    .on('click', 'annoucements-close', function () {
      $('announcement-div').hide();
    })
}
```

```css
@keyframes slideInFromRight {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  .1%{
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.announcements-container {
    position: fixed;
    top: 80px;
    right: 20px;
    z-index: 1001;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 300px;
    /* align-items: flex-end; */
}

.announcements-1 {
    animation: slideInFromRight 0.4s ease;
    opacity: 0;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    
  }
  
.announcements-2 {
    /* animation: 0.4s ease-out 0s 1 slideInFromRight; */
    animation: slideInFromRight 0.4s ease;
    opacity: 0;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-delay: .4s;
    margin-top: 15px;
}

.annoucements-header {
    background-color: #1481C3;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: "Proxima Nova Bold";
    padding: 7px 10px;
}

.annoucements-close {
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
    width: 24px;
    height: 36px;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: .85;
}
.annoucements-close:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
.annoucements-close::before,
.annoucements-close::after {
    content: '';
    width: 24px;
    height: 2px;
    background: white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 7px;
    left: 0;
}
.annoucements-close::before {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.annoucements-close::after {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}

/*opened or closed*/
.announcement-div-opened {
    display: none;
}

.announcement-div.opened .announcement-div-opened {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div class="announcements-container">
    <div class="announcement-div announcements-1">
      <div class="annoucements-header">
        <span class="annoucement-type-quantity">2 School Announcements</span>
        <i class="annoucements-close"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="announcement-div announcements-2">
      <div class="annoucements-header">
        <span class="annoucement-type-quantity">1 Admin Announcement</span>
        <i class="annoucements-close"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

As you can see this isn't doing anything. I'm trying to toggle the class from 'open' (`display:block`) to 'closed' (`display:none`) when the `annoucements-close` `<i>` element is clicked on.

And ideally I would like for the second div to slide up when the top one is closed, but first I'd just like to get either one to disappear.

What's wrong with my code where that's not working as expected?

[Link to JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HappyHands31/g8ater5h/8/)

Comment: Structurally, it seems that the "announcement-div" class should be on the "announcements-1" and "announcements-2" elements instead of on the "announcements-container" element.

Comment: You are correct - that is a mistake - edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 issues with your code: the `click()` event is inside the function `initAnnouncements` that doesn't get called. You could move it outside of this function or call the function. Then you have issues with your selectors: It's

```
 .on('click', '.annoucements-close', function () {
  $('.announcement-div').hide();
})
```

instead of

```
.on('click', 'annoucements-close', function () {
  $('announcement-div').hide();
})
```

for class selectors. Working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tdkc368g/1/).

If you just want to hide the annoucement which was clicked upon, just change it to

```
 .on('click', '.annoucements-close', function () {
     $(this).closest('.announcement-div').hide();
 })
```

Comment: Also, this will close *all* `.announcement-div` elements when clicking *any* `.announcements-close` element.

Comment: @showdev Yes, but I thought this was the intention of the OP.

Comment: As @showdev mentioned, I'll want to target the specific div that is getting closed.

Answer (score 1):

I looked at your code and adjusted it a little to demonstrate:

- Added your common class on the two announcements "announcement-div"
- Attached the document click handler with the jQuery ready event
- Used the delegated event selector to listen to clicks within the document that match that common selector
- On click of one of the announcement-div's animate the height to 0 and then remove the element

Comments are included in the fiddle. Hope this is helpful!

```
// Fire this function when the document is ready
$(function() {
    // Listen on the whole document for click events on the .announcement-div element
    $(document).on('click', '.annoucements-close', function () {
        // From the close button find the closest parent "announcement-div"
        var annoucement = $(this).closest('.announcement-div'); 
        // Function to run after animating the element (use .hide() to keep element but display:none)
        function destroy() { 
            annoucement.remove(); 
        }
        // Animate the annoucement's height to 0 over 400ms and then call the destroy function
        annoucement.animate({ height: "0px" }, 400, destroy);  
    });
});
```

[Updated JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Jscherbe/vbj2qrg3/34/)